# Compute rowMeans across different columns in each row

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I've a DF like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 start end
                    1 2 2 1 2 3 2 6 
                    2 3 2  5  7  9 1 3 
                    1 9 12 6 1 1 3 6 ", header = TRUE)
```

`start` and `end`indicate the number of the columns that should be included in the `rowMeans`. i.e. First row: mean from x2 to x6; Second row: mean from x1 to x3 and so on

I tried this with no success:

```
df$means <- rowMeans(df[,df$X7:df$X8])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[x[7]:x[8]], na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1] 2.000000 2.333333 5.000000
```

A bit of a description. `apply` will iterate over each row. variable `x` represents each row. So, we are telling R to subset each row based on columns 7 and 8 and then calculate the mean.

Comment: No way for using `rowMeans`?

Comment: I cannot think of anything fast. `rowMeans` needs a data.frame or a matrix to calculate the means, which means that you would need to subset your original data.frame (possibly with a loop) to construct a new one with the right columns and NAs where needed in order to make the dimensions right. I think the `apply` would be much faster. Is it performance that worries you?

Comment: if you want to use `rowMeans` you could think of setting values to NA when not in the range of interest. But not sure it will be faster than LyrandeR solution

Comment: Since I received `Warning message:argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`, I updated the @LyzandeR code as follows: `apply(df, 1, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[x[7]:x[8]], na.rm = TRUE)))`